# How would I say "I wish you (pl. formal) sth." in German. Is it necessary to use "für" in the German sentence?

Tags: objects

If I want to express a wish to someone, and I say "Ich wünsche mich *für* Ihnen etw....", is it necessary to use "für", or can I just say, "Ich wünsche mich Ihnen etw....".

In general, is it okay to omit "für" for indirect objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would strongly recommend to avoid the term *indirect object* with respect to German. It may make sense to linguists, but for learners of German it is almost always a source of confusion.

If you wish someone something, the one you wish it is in dative, and the thing you wish is in accusative. Example:

> Ich wünsche Ihnen[dat.] eine gute Reise[akk.].
>
> I wish you a nice journey.

You may use *für* if what you wish is intended for some purpose or some third person. For example:

> Ich wünsche Ihnen gutes Wetter für Ihre Reise.
>
> I wish you good weather for your journey.
>
> Ich wünsche mir eine Pflanze für meinen Garten.
>
> I would like to have a plant for my garden.

*Für Ihnen* is always wrong by the way, because *für* always requires accusative.

Comment: Okay, but my German textbook uses the term "indirect object."

Comment: In some regions of Germany, you find sentences like "Einen schönen Abend für Sie!" instead of "Einen schönen Abend Ihnen!" ("Have a nice evening!"), but as I'm not from one of those regions, I find it strange, so I definitely don't recommend this formulation to non-native speakers, as it doesn't add something new to your capabilities to express something in German...